# Best way to store sstring and translations in a program

Tags: java, string, internationalization

I am making a program to help students learning a second language for my school. The main function of this program will be flash cards. What I am having trouble with is figuring out how to store said words and their respective translations. Would an array be the best way to do this? My teacher has talked for a whole two seconds on arrays so I only know the general purpose of them.

Also how would I call those stored, corresponding strings so the user can see them? If there is some better and more efficient way to store them, I would love to find out.

Edit: I also plan to allow the user to input the words through a text field or something of the sort, if that changes the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should store the said words and their respective translations into a [HashMap](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-hashmap) with said word is key, and value is the translation. And to get the stored, just find by key.

Answer (score 0):

A `Map<String, String>` would be the perfect data type for mapping one `String` to another.  I would definitely read up on the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) if I were you.

For example:

```
Map<String, String> translatedWords = new HashMap<>();

translatedWords.put("Hello", "Hola");

System.out.println(translatedWords.get("Hello"));

>> "Hola"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 2D array, because it uses rows and columns. Consider the following example, it is Spanish:

```
String[][] array = new String[][]{
    {"You","Tu"},
    {"Sandwich","Bocadillo"},
    {"You eat a sandwich","Tu comes un bocadillo"}
};
```

Look at this Javadoc for more info: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E58500_01/pt854pbh1/eng/pt/tpcr/task_CreatingandPopulatingMulti-DimensionalArrays-071663.html#topofpage

**EDIT:**

It looks like you are trying to have the user input their own words and translations... Unless you use file reading and writing, this is going to be a really difficult process. This is an example of a way to store translations via file writing, if I learn more about `2D` `ArrayLists`, I'll get back to you.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a word:");

    String word = sc.nextLine(); 
    //You can also use textfields: word = textfield.getText();

    System.out.println("Please enter the translation:");

    String trans = sc.nextLine();

    //Always use UTF-8 if you are using any European or American alphabets
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("lang.txt", "UTF-8");
     /*
      * You can name the file anyting you want, with any extension: 
      *"Cake.weirdFile, Juice.lump, Ilike.Chicken" 
      *it should be readable by Java as long as you use UTF-8
      */
    pw.print(word); 
    pw.println(trans);
    pw.close();
    //Make sure to catch/throw FileNotFoundException & UnsupportedEncodingException
```

And you can read the file for flash card quizzes/reviews:

```
         Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(new File("lang.txt"));
        //Make sure to catch/throw FileNotFoundException

        String[] wordAndTrans = sc2.nextLine().split(" ");

        sc2.close();

        System.out.println("The translation of '" 
                              + wordAndTrans[0] + "' is: '" +  wordAndTrans[1] + "'");
```

Although this code works, I wouldn't suggest copy/pasting this because the way it is laid out might not be compatible with *your* code. This is merely an example usage of `Scanners`, `PrintWriters`, and `String` **splitting** so you can save your translations each to their own line in a file.

Comment: How would I allow the user to input their own words, instead of some predetermined ones? Thanks heaps for the answer!!

Comment: @A.Price is there a specific number of words they can input? Because if not,  then we will have to use a 2d ArrayList which are pains to make...

Comment: @A.Price if you don't have a limit to inputs, then storing in an object is nearly impossible (for me as least). Consider my edit

Answer (score 0):

It can be taken as a simple one and challenging one also. If you expecting a simple idea then you can use a Map. then store the key as first language word and value as second language word,These are the map implementations

```
 HashMap (if you need more speed then use this implementation)
  Map<String,String> translatedValues = new HashMap();
 LinkedHahMap (If you need the data as the same oreder of insertion)
 TreeMap (Less speed but sorted one)
```

Answer (score 0):

### [ResourceBundle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/propfile.html)

Also known as properties files

Don't clutter your code with Hashmaps and arrays. You also can have additional translations without editing any Java code

> A properties file is a simple text file. You can create and maintain a properties file with just about any text editor

```
# This is the default LabelsBundle.properties file
s1 = computer
s2 = disk
s3 = monitor
s4 = keyboard
```

> To support an additional Locale, your localizers will create a new properties file that contains the translated values. No changes to your source code are required, because your program references the keys, not the values.

```
# This is the LabelsBundle_de.properties file
s1 = Computer
s2 = Platte
s3 = Monitor
s4 = Tastatur
```

### Use

```
Locale currentLocale;
ResourceBundle labels = ResourceBundle.getBundle("LabelsBundle", currentLocale);

String computer = labels.getString("s1");
```